# I have an error with my API fetching, what does it mean

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I was trying to retrieve data from an API and it worked for several days but now, it gives this error:

```
[Error] Preflight response is not successful
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://imdb-api.com/en/API/Search/my_key/m due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (m, line 0)
```

What does this mean?

By the way, here's the code(relatively simple):

```
export async function getAPI(url, settings, callback) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, settings)
        var result = await response.json()
        callback(result)
    } catch {
        callback({errorMessage: "This is an error message"})
    }
}
```

Does it have something to do with the code or something else?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: This might be happening because of CORS issue

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Not related to the issue but passing a callback function to the `getAPI` function defeats the purpose of using the `async-await` syntax. You could return the `result` and in the calling code either `await` it or chain a `then` method call to the `getAPI` function call.

Comment: Browser makes a preflight request to the url before making the actual request to check if Cross origin request are allowed or not. Seems like CORS is not enabled.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a browser mechanism which enables controlled access to resources located outside of a given domain

Comment: Thanks a lot, now checking it

Comment: I checked if it was just me or the server is down by the help of the site https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com

Comment: It said that the server itself was down at the moment

Comment: I'll have to wait I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is either a CORS issue or perhaps has something to do with your header